# Pivot Table - How to copy sum value onto another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google

I have set up 3 sheets in Google sheets in related to budgeting/expenses.

The first contains the full budget (say Sheet A for example);
The second contains the expenses (Sheet B);
and the Third contains the pivot table (Sheet C), which helps to group together all the different expenses from Sheet B into categories.

The pivot table is used to separate all the expenses into their relevant category and provide a sum total of the amount spent within that particular category. I want to copy this sum total amount to Sheet A. At first, I set a simple formula

Excel Formula: ='Sheet C'!C5

But the problem is, every time I add a new expense to Sheet B, the sum total value will be moved down to say C6 and so on. Is there some kind of formula I can use to copy the sum total value to Sheet A?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [getpivotdata()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538) function. Try this in cell `'Sheet A'!F6`:

`=getpivotdata("SUM of Requested", 'Sheet C'!A$1, "Budget catagory and description", C6)`

Alternatively, get the sum directly from the source data, like this:

`=sumif('Sheet B'!B$4:B, C6, 'Sheet B'!D$4:D)`

...or:

`=query('Sheet B'!B$4:D, "select sum(D) where B = '" & C6 & "' label sum(D) '' ", 0)`

Comment: How would that work? Here's an example of the spreadsheet I mentioned - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FKQFnNIWhlu7Mvb9p014t4y5VQ3q9fNL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107928677245444806209&rtpof=true&sd=true

I want the sum total value in the pivot table to be shown and updated in the 'Requested' section of sheet A. But every time a new value is entered in Sheet B, the order of the pivot table and the sum value changs.

Comment: Edited the answer per your sample spreadsheet.